# How to add datasource to textbox in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, vb.net, textbox

In my form I have drop down list that displays products

and a textbox that should display the price for the selected product

My question is how can I add datasource into the textbox ?

Comment: You can not add data source to textbox. But you _can_ add the value that data source returns to your textbox. Any effort to solve it by the way? If you do, show your work and tell where you stuck. We need more details about your problem.

Comment: I tried to add stored procedure to display the data in the textbox  but it didn't work !

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Event-Handler to the drop-down list that gets called, when the user selects a different value in the drop-down list.

Then simply change the value of the textbox in the event-handler method.

Hope this helps, please comment if you need more information.

Comment: ok , but I need to know how to show the price for each product from the database in this textbox(I mean how to add datasource for the textbox) . Do you get what I mean ?

Comment: Not really.
You can alter the Text-Value of the textbox in the Event-Handler.
Why do you even need a datasource?

Or do you mean, that you can't access the values that you want to set to the textbox and mean this by a datasource?

Comment: I need the price for the selected item from the drop down list to be displyed in the textbox ... That's why I asked how to add datasource to the textbox

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem !

I used datalist insted of textbox and I configured its datasource

to retrive the price for any chosen product from the drop down list

```
 <ItemTemplate>
                Price:
                <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>' />
                <br />
<br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```